# c# updating datagridview using sqlcommand

Tags: c#, datagridview

I've tried to update my datagridview. (edited)

My code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=tcp:SHEN-PC,49172\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LSEStock;Integrated Security=True";
        con.Open();


        if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {   
            int nRowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Count-2;

            if (dataGridView1.Rows[nRowIndex].Cells[1].Value != null)
            {
                textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[nRowIndex].Cells[1].Value);
                String updateData = "UPDATE CostPrice SET SupplierName = @SupplierName, CostPrice = @CostPrice WHERE PartsID = '" +textBox1.Text+"'";
                SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand(updateData, con);
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(updateData, con);

                update.Parameters.Add("@SupplierName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "SupplierName");
                update.Parameters.Add("@CostPrice", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "CostPrice");
                adapter.UpdateCommand = update;

                //update.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (update != null)
                {
                    update.Dispose();
                    update = null;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("NULL");
            }
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

It says that ExecuteNonQuery is not initialized. What's wrong with my codes?

I'm using SqlCommand to update, but what I see from the internet almost everyone is using SqlDataAdapter, what's the difference? Thanks in advance.

If you have a better code, I would like to learn from that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can read up about [Data Adapter Vs Sql Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569012/data-adapter-vs-sql-command)

To overcome the error, I believe you need to assign the command's Connection = con

```
update.Connection = con;
```

Here is the reference: [SqlCommand.Connection Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.connection.aspx)

Or in this line:

```
SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand(updateData, con);
```

ps Don't forget to dispose SqlCommand objects once your done with them:

```
if (sqlCommand != null)
{
    sqlCommand.Dispose();
    sqlCommand = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1st: make sure your Update Query is Correct

Update Syntax:

```
   UPDATE [TableName] SET [CoulumnName]='new value' where [ColumnName]='yourFilterValue'
```

your update query must be somthing like this:

```
 String updateData = "UPDATE CostPrice SET CostID = @CostID, SupplerName = @SupplierName, CostPrice = @CostPrice WHERE PartsID = @PartsID";
```

2nd: You just missed to add the sqlconnection on your sqlcommand.

```
SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand(updateData,con);
```

3rd: You have Parameters on your query but you even not set its values.

check this sample on csharp-station : [ado.net lesson 6](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/lesson06)

this your code will look like:

```
string updateData = "UPDATE CostPrice SET SupplierName = @SupplierName, CostPrice = @CostPrice WHERE PartsID =@PartsID";
SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand(updateData, con);

update.Parameters.Add("@SupplierName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "SupplierName");
update.Parameters.Add("@CostPrice", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "CostPrice");
update.Parameters.Add("@PartsID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50,textBox1.Text);
update.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Regards

Comment: but then it shows me "Incorrect syntax near ','. at the executenonquery() line

Comment: i've changed my code, no error occured, but the database is not updating. can u take a look pls?

Comment: remove  SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(updateData, con); and adapter.Update(); and just use    update.ExecuteNonQuery(); that's it.it will work. :D vote up and mark as answer.

Comment: oh my, it comes out with this "The parameterized query '(@SupplierName nvarchar(50),@CostPrice nvarchar(50))UPDATE CostP' expects the parameter '@SupplierName', which was not supplied."

Answer (score 0):

as Jeremy Thompson suggested, you are missing one line of code.

```
update.Connection = con;
```

Add this code just before calling `update.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: but then it shows me "Incorrect syntax near ','. at the executenonquery line