# how can i get the description of the user who is logged in at that moment using two different database table?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database

tblUsers

```
ID | username | password 
---+----------+-----  
1  | admin    | admin
2  | test     | test
```

tblDescription

```
descId | userID | description
-------+--------+-------------
  1    |   2    | this is for the test description
  2    |   1    | this is for the admin description
```

I have tried to build my database a little bit up.

I have created two different tables in my SQL database (`tblUsers` and `tblDescription`) and of course every user has an id

But what I want to do is when a user logs in ,

it will check the id of the user who is logged in and display the description.

I've been able to create the login with forms authentication in c# but I can't figure out how to get the description of the user?

I've done a couple research as I'm new to database but I still couldn't get it

Can I get some help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on page_load event 
use query

```
select Description from tbl_description where UserID=Session["UserID"];
```

Maintain session at login page and use that session to fetch the description like this 
and show wherever you want
hope this will help

Comment: this is what i have, "select userdesc.dealer_discription from userdesc  
inner join tblUsers on userdesc.UserId = tblUsers.Id" and after i execute i get all the discription, how can i specify for just one ID?

Comment: well,
if u are using asp.net with C# then maintain a session in login page 
like 
`SqlDataAdapter da=new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblUsers where username='"+txtuserName.Text+"' and username='"+txtpassword.Text+"'",yourConnectionString);
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
da.fill(dt);
if(dt.rows.count>0){
//maintain session over here
Session["userID"]=dt.row[0]["ID"];
Redirect to your page
}`
select userdesc.dealer_discription from userdesc inner join tblUsers on userdesc.UserId = tblUsers.Id where tblUsers.Id=Session["UserID"];
hope this will help now

Answer (score 0):

With an INNER JOIN on the tblDescription based on ID ? Take a look here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp . Have fun

Comment: i used the inner join and it worked in the sql , if i want to implement it to c#, do i use sqldataadapter of sqlcommand?

Comment: take a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569012/data-adapter-vs-sql-command

Comment: this is what i have, "select userdesc.dealer_discription from userdesc  
inner join tblUsers on userdesc.UserId = tblUsers.Id" and after i execute i get all the discription, how can i specify for just one ID?

Comment: WHERE ID = 1 for example see @Peter example

Answer (score 0):

When you say that you are **Authenticating** its basically you are calling a service which gives you some data , in this token or a response telling that the user has logged in .
In your service you would be accessing database to query some details (user_id , password) , in this level (service) try to make a db call in the same session to fetch the user details from your database (Any table) .

For that you can use **Joins** in your query to retrieve from multiple tables .

If any queries , do comment and i will edit the answer if needed .

Comment: and do i use sqlcommand to write the query or sqldataadapter?

Comment: you can use multiple approaches to query from DB in your asp.net app , yes you can use sqlDataAdapter , EntityFramework , etc .

Comment: http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson04  This may help you

Comment: this is what i have, "select userdesc.dealer_discription from userdesc  
inner join tblUsers on userdesc.UserId = tblUsers.Id" and after i execute i get all the discription, how can i specify for just one ID?

Comment: In the end of the query write a "where" clause , tblUserts.Id = "user id which u want to search"

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this as you've described is to use a **trigger**.

When you say you want the description, do you mean you want the username of the person who logged in or changed something? If so use something like this?

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_update_paid ON UnPaidFees2017
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN


UPDATE UnPaidFees2017
SET DateChanged = GETDATE(), [User] = USER_NAME()
FROM UnPaidFees2017, inserted
WHERE UnPaidFees2017.ID = inserted.ID

END
```

That is an example I used before. You can change it up a bit.

Comment: this is what i have, "select userdesc.dealer_discription from userdesc  
inner join tblUsers on userdesc.UserId = tblUsers.Id" and after i execute i get all the discription, how can i specify for just one ID?